# ¿Existe un término más "culto" que sordo para referirse a quien no puede oír?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

En el foro de Word Reference se pregunta por [la diferencia entre *ciego* e *invidente*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ciego-invidente.1736597/). Alguien sugiere que la palabra *invidente* es más culta, mientras que otro usuario dice que más que culta es "el cinismo del políticamente correcto".

Dejando de lado el hecho de si *invidente* es una palabra culta o una palabra para cumplir con una normativa social, ¿tenemos una versión similar para la palabra "sordo"?

Comment: No conozco ningún sinónimo, pero [este artículo](https://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-16607679) puede ser de interés. Afirma que *sordo* no tiene tal percepción ofensiva como e.j. *sordito, mudito* o *sordomudo*: `Sordo... no resulta peyorativo` `“No se dice sordomudo ni mudo en ninguna circunstancia. Hay un altísimo porcentaje de sordos que sí habla. Sobre la discriminación puedo decir que el resultado es más importante que la intención` `Sordito o mudito son ofensas comunes y muy fuertes porque irrespetan los derechos fundamentales. Reducen al sujeto y le imprime lástima.`

Comment: No sé si funciona así también en español, pero en inglés los sordos aceptan el término *sordo* con orgullo.

Answer (score 4):

[`Hipoacusia`](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KSSiejw) es la disminución de la capacidad auditiva y a los que la sufren se los llama `hipoacúsicos` (el término no aparece en el DRAE).

La hipoacusia se puede clasificar en leve, moderada, severa y profunda. Un hipoacúsico severo o profundo sería un sordo hecho y derecho, mientras que uno leve o moderado sería un medio sordo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el eufemismo para sordo es Persona Sordomuda,

Según esta fuente(mati)[1] : se aconseja referirse a ellos como "Personas" y no simplemente por su padecimiento/discapacidad/perdida

Los eufemismos para sordo son :

- Persona sordomuda
- Persona sorda
- Persona con discapacidad auditiva
- Persona con hipocaucia

1: http://www.webmati.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46:terminos-adecuados-para-referirnos-a-personas-con-discapacidad&catid=14&Itemid=163